# Mips program has infinite loop, also cant figure out how to increment values properly?

Tags: assembly, mips

For my program I am taking in user input and swapping the values of the input if the first number given is larger than the second. I do this so that when I move to IsAmicable the values for the small and larger number is the same no matter how the user enters them in. The program right now is not complete, I will later be using the inputed range values for something else, but for now I am stuck on getting my for loop to work. I am passing the small and large number to IsAmicable and setting a loop adding from the small number up until the small number is equal to the big number. At that point I would like it to exit the program. The only issue is that somewhere in my code the small number is not being iterated correctly causing the program to have an infinite loop.

I should add here that I have another function called IsFactor with another for loop in there to find what numbers are divisors of x number. I am wanting to store these numbers that are divisors as a sum and also pass that back to IsAmicable. I am not sure if my code is going wrong in the IsAmicable function, or if its the IsFactor function.

My question is where my program is causing an infinite loop, and if my incrementation of values is working in my loops?

Hopefully I am not being to confusing with this, but any help would be great!

My code is below with my entire program.

```
 .data 
 sent1: .asciiz "Input the start of the range: "
 sent2: .asciiz "Input the end of the range: "
 sent4: .asciiz "IN ELSE "
 

 userInput: .word 20
 userInput2: .word 20
 number: .space 20
 number2: .space 20
 
.text
 main:
    
 addi $sp, $sp, -8    # Add space on the stack for two words
 
 li $v0, 4            # Loads immediate for a sentace to be printed
 la $a0, sent1        # Loads the address of the sentance to print 
 syscall              # System calls and prints out sentance

 li $v0, 5
 syscall
 move $t1, $v0
 
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, sent2
 syscall
 
 li $v0, 5
 syscall 
 move $t2, $v0

 move $a1, $t1
 move $a2, $t2
 slt $s0, $a2, $a1
 bne  $s0, $zero, Else
 jal IsAmicable
 
 Else:
 
 move $a3, $a1
 move $a1, $a2
 move $a2, $a3
 
 jal IsAmicable
 
 Endif:
 li $v0, 10
 syscall
 
 IsAmicable:
 li $v0, 1
 la $t4,($a1)
 jal loop
 loop:
 la $a1, ($t4)
 beq $a1, $a2, Endif   # Setup for loop from value in a1 to value in a2
 addi $a1, $a1, 1      # Adds 1 to a1 to iterate
                       # loads value in a1 to address in a0 to pass to isFactor
 jal IsFactor
 continue:
 la $a0, ($a2)
 move $a3, $a0
 syscall
 
 j loop
 
 
 
 IsFactor:
 
 la $a0, ($a1)
 add $a3, $zero, $zero
 add $a2, $zero, $zero
 
 move $a3, $0
 li $a3, 0
 
 jal loop2
 
 loop2:
 move $a0, $v0
 
 move $t4, $0
 li $t4, 0
 
 bgt $a3, $a0, continue  
 addi $a3, $a3, 1 
 div $a1, $a3
 mfhi $t4
 bne $t4, $zero,loop2
 add $a2, $a2, $a3
 j loop2
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the `jal` instruction. I see several `jal` instructions - sometimes used very strangely, like jumping to the very next line - but not a single `jr`.

Comment: Try single-stepping through your code with the debugger.  You're using MARS / SPIM system calls, and both those simulators have debuggers built-in.  That should show you how your current program is executing, and what register values are if/when your `beq` to `Endif` is reached.